# how to solve Exception has occurred

Tags: flutter

i tried to implement twitter login but I keep getting this error "Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(400, Failed to generate request token., Please check your APIKey or APISecret., null))".
Can anyone help with this error??

[image]

Comment: Well, *did you* "check your APIKey or APISecret."?

Comment: yes I regenerated new keys too but I keep getting this error.

Comment: I'm not sure who wrote this code, maybe it was generated. You may want to look at the actual exception (the one caught, not the one thrown) to see what the error was. Maybe it was the wrong URL or the service was not available or you are not online. Could be all kinds of things. Try to get the actual exception message.